# How can I call my func for PyQt5 calculator?

Tags: python, function, pyqt5, calculator, qt-designer

I am trying to make a calculator by using pyqt5 and Qt Designer.My code runs ,no seems any error.
When the program runs "display_screen" func runs  but program doesn't enter into "calculation" function.
How can I fix this?Thanks.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import sys

class calculator_main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('calculator.ui',self)
        self.pushButton_0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("0"))
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("1"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("2"))
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("3"))
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("4"))
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("5"))
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("6"))
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("7"))
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("8"))
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("9"))
        self.pushButton_dot.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("."))
        self.pushButton_00.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("00"))
        self.pushButton_add.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("+"))
        self.pushButton_minus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("-"))
        self.pushButton_multiply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("*"))
        self.pushButton_divide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.display_screen("/"))
        self.pushButton_equal.clicked.connect(lambda:self.calculation)
        self.pushButton_sil.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.backspace)
        self.pushButton_clear.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)

    def display_screen(self,value):
        self.lineEdit.insert(value)
        print("display func runned")

    def calculation(self):
        screen_value = str(self.lineEdit.text()).split(' ')
        if screen_value[1] == "+":
            return screen_value[0] + screen_value[2]
        elif screen_value[1] == "-":
            return screen_value[0] - screen_value[2]
        elif screen_value[1] == "*":
            return screen_value[0] * screen_value[2]
        elif screen_value[1] == "/":
            return screen_value[0] / screen_value[2]
        print(screen_value[2])
        print("calculation func runned")

uygulama=QApplication([])
pencere=calculator_main()
pencere.show()
uygulama.exec()
```

Comment: please provide a    `calculator.ui`

Comment: use `self.pushButton_equal.clicked.connect(self.calculation)` or `self.pushButton_equal.clicked.connect(lambda:self.calculation())`